# Will the acceleration of a triangular wedge affect relative acceleration of a particle parallel to the inclined plane (the wedges surface)?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration, vectors, free-body-diagram

[image: Below is an example of the sort of problem i am referring to]

I was wondering if the **horizontal** acceleration of a triangular wedge will effect the acceleration of a particle on the wedges surface (because the wedge is triangular this will be an inclined plane) **relative to the wedge**. That is will it affect the acceleration of the particle parallel to the surface that is the inclined plane of the particle. This is in a scenario that disregards friction.

That is to say if a wedge is accelerating will it have an impact on the relative acceleration of a particle on the inclined surface of the wedge?

Answer (score 1):

With respect to wedge , there will be no effect on the acceleration of the body,when you accelerate the wedge.

But with ground frame of reference , motion will change according to acceleration of the wedge.That you can figure it out with concept of pseudo force.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Unless a reference frame has uniform rectilinear motion- i.e., an inertial frame, objects within that reference frame will appear to have forces acting on them proportional to their mass and the acceleration of the frame. The diagram on the left, from a stationary frame, describes the normal force acting on and accelerating barrier by way of Newton's 3rd Law. From the non-inertial frame of the accelerated object, this appears as a pseudo-force acting on the object in much the same way that the gravitational force would. Thus, in the diagram on the right, the motion of the particle on the wedge in the non-inertial frame may be calculated in the same way as it would be in an inertial frame with the gravitational force.